# Getting file name in git pre commit hook

Tags: linux, git, github

I have one git pre-commit hook, which check for console.log. It is working. I want to have file name also, please help.

```
#!/bin/sh
    # Redirect output to stderr.
    exec 1>&2
    # enable user input
    exec < /dev/tty

    consoleregexp='console.log'
    # CHECK
    if test $(git diff --cached | grep $consoleregexp | wc -l) != 0
    then 
      exec git diff --cached | grep -ne $consoleregexp
      read -p "There are some occurrences of console.log at your modification. Are you sure want to continue? (y/n)" yn
      echo $yn | grep ^[Yy]$
      if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
      then
        exit 0; #THE USER WANTS TO CONTINUE
      else
        exit 1; # THE USER DONT WANT TO CONTINUE SO ROLLBACK
      fi
    fi
```

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot make sense out of this question. Which file's name do you want to have? Or do you want a list of *all* names of all the files that would be changed by this commit? What if some of the changes are `chmod`s rather than content-changes? Do you want to detect renames? (What's the real goal here?)

Comment: @torek, I am just doing this git pre-hook first time. I want that whatever files have console.log, its names should be displayed

Comment: Ah, you mean that `git diff` has found `console.log` in the text of the diff, and you want to know: *which file(s) had that text in it/them?* (Note that `git diff` may have found that `console.log` was *removed* from the file's content, since `git diff` shows both the old and new content.)

Comment: You could run a grep command to find things you don't want in the commit. I have hooks that search for conflict markers for instance  `git grep -E --cached "^[><=]{7}"` and then exit with 1 if found, preventing the commit